# Delphi TBytes - how to copy?

Tags: arrays, delphi

Point is opimization here.

Now:

```
type TSomeClass=class(TObject)
  private
    DataWrite: TBytes;
  ...
end;

Function TSomeClass.GetPacket: TBytes;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(DataWrite));
  Move(DataWrite[0],Result[0],Length(DataWrite));
end;
```

What I want to achieve:

```
Function TSomeClass.GetPacket: TBytes;
begin
  Result := DataWrite;
end;
```

Because Arrays in Delphi are pointers to first element, the latter only and only writes 4 bytes so it is MUCH faster. Is this correct?

Comment: do you want to copy the data or copy the reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That will work but note that you are now working on the same byte array in client code that calls `GetPacket`. This might be a bad idea. Consider some network library that does some additional compression or encryption on the byte array. This creates a lot of possibilites to interact with your class without using the exposed interface - which is bad. Thus IMHO copying is the better option here.

BTW: How big are the arrays we are talking about here?

Comment: Thanks! Only the confirmation I needed. ;)

Comment: The class is for generic Writing/Reading. And I'd like to use GetPacket in order to send it and yes, encryption is going to be done on the byte array of the reader/writer.

Answer (score 7):

The one thing you need to be aware of is that different from strings, dynamic arrays are not "copy-on-write".

If you assign a string, or a dynamic array, only the pointer to the data on the heap is copied and the reference count is incremented.

But with a string, if you then write into a string (e.g. s[1] := 'a') which has a reference count > 1, the compiler will emit code which makes sure that the string is copied first. This is not the case with dynamic arrays:

```
var 
  s, t: string;
  a, b: TBytes;
begin
  s := 'abc';
  t := s;
  t[2] := 'X';
  WriteLn(s); //still abc

  a := TBytes.Create(1, 2, 3);
  b := a;
  b[1] := 0;
  WriteLn(a[1]); // is now 0 not 2!
```

So in case of your code, if you change the contents of DataWrite after GetPacket was called, the change will be visible in the TBytes that GetPacket returned.

For the code where you actually make a copy of the array, instead of calling SetLength And Move, you can use:

```
function TSomeClass.GetPacket: TBytes;
begin
  Result := Copy(DataWrite, 0, High(Integer));
end;
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference in copy-on-write semantics between strings and dynamic arrays.

Comment: Or simpler yet you can just write
  Result := Copy(DataWrite);

Comment: @Larsdk, thanks, didn't know that. Never tried it and Code Insight does not show the last 2 parameters as optional.